# error when switching between activity android

Tags: android, android-intent

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button ok = findViewById(R.id.ok);
        ok.setText("OK");

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, second.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Switching to another page does not occur, the application crashes
most likely the problem is this: 
`Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, second.class);`

Comment: What's the stacktrace of the crash? copy it from logcat and paste here. and is second extending `Activity` as well? And is it defined in `AndroidManifest`

Comment: Please add the crash stacktrace from Logcat to your question.

Comment: --------- beginning of crash
05-14 08:30:22.734 2252-2252/com.itmo.myprogram2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.itmo.myprogram2, PID: 2252
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.itmo.myprogram2/com.itmo.myprogram2.second}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
and much more...

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure both activities extend `AppCompatActivity` or `Activity` (I recommend extending `AppCompatActivity`, and as naming convention, I suggest renaming `second` to `SecondActivity` and make sure `SecondActivity` also extends `AppCompatActivity`.

Then go to `AndroidManifest.xml` and make sure `SecondActivity` is defined like:
`<activity android:name=".path.to.SecondActivity"` (Make sure you use the correct path, you could start writing `sec..` in the field and the IDE will suggest activities for you.

EDIT:

Based on op's comment, this should be the solution:
`android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` in the second's declaration in `AndroidManifest` for ex:

`<activity android:name=".path.to.SecondActivity"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>`

Comment: @lisa make sure to mark the answer as correct and remove the downvote, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Possible causes of this type of error are:

1. second is not an Activity (does not extend Activity).
2. second is not declared in your AndroidManifest.
3. Some code within the second Activity onCreate() is generating this exception.